# Can't pass data between classes

Tags: c#, kinect

I am developing a Kinect application based on VS2012 using winform. After I tried several methods, I still couldn't pass value from one class to another class.

Basically I have three class, a public `MainWindow()`, public partial `FaceTrackingViewer()`, and public `SkeletonFaceTracker()`. The last class reside in `FaceTrackingViewer()` class.

In SkeletonFaceTracker(), I have the following:

```
public bool lastFaceTrackSucceeded { get; set; }

internal void OnFrameReady(KinectSensor kinectSensor, ColorImageFormat colorImageFormat, byte[] colorImage, DepthImageFormat depthImageFormat, short[] depthImage, Skeleton skeletonOfInterest)
{
    // something else
    if (this.faceTracker != null)
    {
        this.lastFaceTrackSucceeded = frame.TrackSuccessful; //where it's set to be true.
        //something else
    }
}
```

I also tried to change to first line to:

```
public bool lastFaceTrackSucceeded;

public bool LastFaceTrackSucceeded
{
    get { return lastFaceTrackSucceeded; }
    private set { lastFaceTrackSucceeded = value; }
}
```

I think the two are the same though.

In MainWindow(), I have:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    //some other irrelevant code snippets

    private FaceTrackingViewer.SkeletonFaceTracker skeletonFaceTracker = new FaceTrackingViewer.SkeletonFaceTracker();

    private void button_faceOnly_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        bool faceTrackSucceeded = skeletonFaceTracker.lastFaceTrackSucceeded;
        // if I use the second structure in SkeletonFaceTracker(), it should be:
        // bool faceTrackSucceeded = skeletonFaceTracker.LastFaceTrackSucceeded;

        if (faceTrackSucceeded == true )
        {
             //do something
        }
    }
}
```

However, the `bool faceTrackSucceeded` is always `false`, even if the `lastFaceTrackSucceeded` or `LastFaceTrackSucceeded` in `SkeletonFaceTracker()` is `true`. I am very confused and don't know where it went wrong.

Please note that all the video processing and face tracking actions occur in `FaceTrackingViewer()` class. I simply want to pass some parameters and structures to `MainWindow()`.

Thank you

Comment: Are you sure there is only one `SkeletonFaceTracker` being instanced?  You don't show where the field gets set to true.

Comment: Yes, it gets set to true within the SkeletonFaceTracker() Class, I didn't show it in the post though. Let me modify it then.

Comment: YotaXP asked whether the instance of `SkeletonFaceTracker` where the field is being set to true is the same one in `MainWindow`. Is the `skeletonFaceTracker` that's being created in `MainWindow` the one that's actually being used?

Comment: I think so, I only have one `SkeletonFaceTracker` and only make it an instance in `MainWindow` once. But I am not sure if the `skeletonFaceTracker` that's being created in `MainWindow` is the one that's actually being used. I mean, all the currently using data structures should be in `skelentonFaceTracker` class, I only want to get some values out from it in `MainWindow` class. How could I check it though?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One thing first - I assume you are making the **variable** `lastFaceTrackSucceeded` public purely for testing purposes. The two ways of defining the property are functionally the same in your example.

The only other thing I can think of is that you are setting `LastFaceTrackSucceeded` true on a *different instance* of `SkeletonFaceTracker`. You haven't provided enough code for me to be sure about this, but if you have two (or more) instances then it can be easy to get them mixed up.

Comment: I have add the snippet where I set the lastFaceTrackSucceeded true, i.e., inside function internal void OnFrameReady. Thank you.

Comment: Indeed as you pointed out, I check the SkeletonFaceTracker class, it's a stupid mistake. Thank you though.